# Check how deep an array goes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, json

I'm receiving data from the [GMail API](https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/) using `$.ajax()` with `dataType: "xml"`, then throwing it into `$.xml2json`, which is a [jQuery plugin](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html). The problem is (as ironically demonstrated by the demo on the page) that when I put in something like this:

```
<animals>
     <dog>
          <name>Rufus</name>
          <breed>labrador</breed>
     </dog>
     <dog>
          <name>Marty</name>
          <breed>whippet</breed>
     </dog>
     <cat name="Matilda"/>
</animals>
```

I get this:

```
{
    animals: {
        dog: [
            {
                name: 'Rufus',
                breed: 'labrador'
            }, {
                name: 'Marty',
                breed: 'whippet'
            }
        ],
        cat: {
            name: 'Matilda'
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, as you can see, in `<animals>` there are two `<dog>`s and only one `<cat>`; therefore, `animals["cat"]` is an object, while `animals["dog"]` is an array of objects. Likewise, when there is only one `<entry>` returned by GMail, `feed["entry"]` is an array of what is inside it, but when there is more than one tag, `feed["entry"]` is an array of entries, which in turn are arrays of what is inside them.

What I want to do is do different things, depending on whether I have 1 or more entries, using a conditional statement; to do that I need a boolean which tells me how many entries there are. How would I go about doing that? JQuery welcome.

EDIT: I guess another possible answer would be to edit the source of the plugin itself and make it offer some sort of way of knowing if it is a lone tag (an array-like object) or if there are lots of them (a "true" array).

Comment: To be clear, `[]` is an array, `{}` is an object. Your question will be clearer if you change the wording accordingly. Also, a boolean is a true/false value – you wouldn't use it for a count of items.

Comment: `animals["dog"]` is actually an array of *objects*. `/NITPICK`

Comment: @glortho I guess. Also, (very annoyingly) calling `typeof` on both of them seems to return "object". Is there any other way to differentiate between the two?

Comment: @glortho - technically, anything that goes inside an `if()` is a boolean; that's what I meant :D

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call( [] )` vs `Object.prototype.toString.call( {} )`

Comment: @pointy - Nice! You might want to put that into an answer before other steal it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `type()` method to streamline your code and take advantage of fully cross browser compliant tests

API Refernce : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {

    switch($.type(item)) {
      case 'string':
        /* string code*/
        break;

      case 'array':
        /* aray code*/
        break;

        /* ....etc*/
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best thing you can do here is to simply `concat` the object/array to an empty array:

```
var obj = {a:"hello"};
[].concat(obj); // [{a:"hello"}]

var arr = [{a:"hello"}];
[].concat(arr); // identical results
```

So to fix your object:

```
for ( var prop in obj ) {
    obj[prop] = [].concat(obj[prop])
}
```

This way you will always get an array and don't have to worry about which one you have.

Comment: That's a slick and concise trick, and it might even be faster, but it's less readable to a future maintainer.

Comment: @zetlen I have to disagree there. Standardizing return types almost always makes things easier for people later on. You can get a single element array, or a 500 element array, but you always know it's an array of objects.

Comment: I completely agree with that! The question is not whether to standardize on an array, but how!

Comment: I was curious about the speed of various kinds of array casting, [so I made a JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/testing-for-an-array-vs-concatting-an-array). `instanceof` won, but it's unreliable, so your method is the best. Good on you!

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason, i.e. if I have an array-like object called `a`, when I concat it, `a[0]` still doesn't work.

Comment: @Bluefire You mean something like this: `var a= ["abcd"];[].concat(a);`?

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = {
    animals: {
        dog: [
            {
                name: 'Rufus',
                breed: 'labrador'
            }, {
                name: 'Marty',
                breed: 'whippet'
            }
        ],
        cat: {
            name: 'Matilda'
        }
    }
};

for ( var i in json ) {
    if ( json.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) {
        if ( json[i] instanceof Array ) {
            // you have an array, do as you please
        } else {
            // you have an object, do as you please
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, but what about arrays of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug in xml2json, and more generally a problem with converting XML to JSON--without a description document like XSLT or XSD, there's no way to tell the serializer that something is supposed to be a collection. You might want to look into something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/) for turning XML into JSON in a more formal manner.

In the meantime, here's a way to force a variable to be an array if it isn't and leave it unchanged if it is:

```
x = [].concat(x);
```

*Note: this was edited after the fact to use @Asad's superior method from his answer*

This starts to fail with multidimensional arrays, as you've observed, so it sounds like you'd better start using XSLT to describe which elements are always collections.

### And don't use `instanceof`

There is an edge case where `instanceof`fails. The `instanceof` operator used like `x instanceof Array` tests whether a particular constructor (in this case `window.Array`) is present in the prototype chain. **But this fails when the variable came from another window**, such as a popup window or an iframe that exists on the same domain and can pass objects directly to its parent.

Comment: Nothing in the original post suggests that data will come from another window object. Your edge case hardly compels a large bold warning.

Comment: In the future I shall type one more # sign into the Markdown box, in order to adhere to your wishes.

Comment: @glortho And actually, when you're doing cross-domain AJAX, one of the more common parlor tricks is to use a cross-domain iframe receiver. Getting less common as browsers get better, but still common enough that any mention of getting JSON from a foreign endpoint does indeed compel such a warning.

Comment: Compels a warning, yes, but not one formatted to communicate end of days.